# Using .save() on peewee record always returns 0

Tags: python, peewee

This problem has been driving me insane. I'm using peewee's `get_or_create` method to get or create a record, change its values, and then save it. I don't understand why, but every time I try to save a record this way, save always returns `0` suggesting that 0 records have been altered in the database. If I used force_insert=True then I get a duplicate entry error. I have tried so many different things trying to get this to work but it just won't.

I've noticed that if I select a record from the AssetOwner database and change it, it works. But for some reason when I use the get_or_create method, the `.save()` function **always** returns `0`. Any ideas? Code for the AssetOwner model, get or create function, and update code below.

```
class AssetOwner(BaseModel):
    asset_id = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Asset, backref='asset')
    owner_id = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Owner, backref='owner')

def goc_assetowner_by_asset(asset_id, owner_id):
    """
    Takes an asset db id and owner db id and gets or creates an AssetOwner
    database record.
    Returns the selected or created AssetOwner record.
    """
    assetowner_record, asset_owner_created = AssetOwner.get_or_create(
        asset_id=asset_id,
        defaults={
            'owner_id': owner_id,
            'last_updated': datetime.datetime.now(),
            'time_created': datetime.datetime.now()
        })
    return (assetowner_record, asset_owner_created)
```

And then later

```
ao_record, ao_created = goc_assetowner_by_asset(
    asset.id,
    last_event.to_account_id
)
if ao_created is False:
    ao_record.asset = asset.id,
    ao_record.owner = last_event.to_account_id
    result = ao_record.save()
```

Comment: Does 0 indicate a successful operation?

Comment: @Phix It indicates that 0 rows were updated. So in this case that would mean failure as I'm trying to update existing records.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say as get_or_creaet() looks for exact match and insert when no matching is found, So try using this instead,

```
try:
    assetOwner = assetOwner.get(
        (#pass parameters)
except AssetOwner.DoesNotExist:
    assetOwner = assetOwner.create(
        #pass parameters)
```

Then perform a save() on AssetOwner Object so that we have more control over whats going on and will get errors accordingly

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking of maybe trying this as a last resort, but you make a good point about the errors potentially being more informative. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems working fine for me:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Reg(Model):
    key = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([Reg])

reg, created = Reg.get_or_create(key='k1')
assert created
reg.key = 'k1-edited'
assert reg.save() == reg.id

reg, created = Reg.get_or_create(key='k1-edited')
assert not created
reg.key = 'k1'
assert reg.save() == reg.id
```